# Short film or television show from the 80s about computer will follow orders exactly as told

Tags: story-identification, tv, short-film

I am looking for a short story shown in the 80s on either HBO or Cinemax about a future society where computers are taking over jobs.

The general plot is that it's hard for anyone to find a job. The main character was lucky to be employed by a big corporation, but has a romantic relationship with one of his colleagues. He wanted the computer to erase his files so that no one knows he's in the building with his lover, and orders the computer not to interrupt unless it's a matter of life or death.

With his files deleted, the security system thinks he's an unauthorized intruder and wanted to exterminate him.  He is chased in an attempt to kill him because of it.  Only at the very last moment does the computer intervene and save him, as he ordered.  It turns out that his lover was also a robot.

Comment: A computer that does what it's told?  Clearly science fiction...